# Spark 2 read.csv - empty values

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to upgrade my project from Spark 1.6 to Spark 2.3.0 and I read the new csv reader is much better (SQLContext.read.csv).

However, the databricks reader handled an empty value in a csv file differently.

For example, if I have a line on a csv:

> 1,Testing,,true

On Spark 1.6 I got a result of:

```
+-------+-------+-----+------+
|    _c0|    _c1|  _c2|   _c3|
+-------+-------+-----+------+
|   1   |Testing|     | true |
+-------+-------+-----+------+
```

However, On Spark 2.3.0 I get:

```
+-------+-------+-----+------+
|    _c0|    _c1|  _c2|   _c3|
+-------+-------+-----+------+
|   1   |Testing| null| true |
+-------+-------+-----+------+
```

I have tried to use the option `.option("nullValue", "")`
But it doesn't seem to be working.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
After checking thoroughly - it seems there is no option in Spark 2.3.0

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried ‘df.na.fill(“”)’?

Comment: I have thought of that, however, it is not exactly what I aim for. That way I fill "" for both blanks read from csv and actual nulls. Isn't there a way or an option to help with that?

Comment: This is so bad...did you find any workaround for this? I'm trying to read a csv with my own supplied schema which have all fields as nullable=true and if there are any empty values it marks everything in the row as null.